# Как запретить индексацию сайта по его IP?

Tags: nginx

Обнаружил проблему - в поисковике почти 10,000 страниц моего сайта, только вместо домена используется IP адрес сервера.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заблокировать индексацию по IP?

Используется VPS с nginx, заточенный под один проект на RoR.

И каз уж такой случай, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как исключить и запретить индексацию `www.*` адресов? Хочу оставить в поисковиках только домены вида `site.com`.

Comment: На каждой странице добавьте `<link rel="canonical" href="https://site.com/url/to/this/page" title="PAGE TITLE" />`.

Comment: @Visman неужели лишние ссылки сами пропадут со временем?

Comment: Зачем-то же ввели канонические адреса!? :) Еще вот это посмотрите: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231 И сюда зайдите https://webmaster.yandex.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ запретить индексацию сайта по его IP - запретить доступ к веб-серверу по его IP. Все остальные способы 100% гарантии не имеют. Пример секции для http (все, что не попадет в секции с `server_name` будет попадать сюда):

```
# default server
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

Если у Вас много IP и какие-то нужны для работы, то, "ненужный" IP, можно запретить, например, так:

```
server {
    listen XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
    return 444;
}
```

Если Вам все же необходим трафик по IP, то используйте ридерект вместо `return 444;`, например такой: `return 301 http://site.com$request_uri;`. Многие, но не все, понимают ответ сервера 301 (перемещено навсегда).

**Документация:**

[Имена сервера](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html)

[listen](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

[server_name](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)